# PHP exec() and shell_exec() not outputting everything

Tags: php, cmd, shell-exec

I am trying to get a certain detail from an external program using shell_exec() in PHP. Here is what I am querying:

> $output = shell_exec('vanitygen.exe 1z');

When doing this in the command prompt on windows it returns this information:

> Difficulty: 1353
>   Pattern: 1z
>   Address: address
>   Privkey: private_key

However, when running the same command using PHP shell_exec (and exec) only this is returned:

> Pattern: 1z
>   Address: address
>   Privkey: private_key

Is there any way to have PHP give all information, including the 'Difficulty: 1353' line?
Thanks.

Comment: I'll bet that the missing output is in STDERR.

Comment: You were right.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the information that I wanted was stored in STDERR.
To get this information, you simply have to append this to the end of the exec query:

> 2>&1

In this case, this turns the query from:

> $output = shell_exec('vanitygen.exe 1z');

to

> $output = shell_exec('vanitygen.exe 1z 2>&1');

Comment: Though it's likely overkill, you can also use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) which allows you to manage all I/O streams for the process.